# AVAudioPlayer hitch before playing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I've an AVAudioPlayer with a MP3-file. But before playing, you'll hear a hitch.
This is my code:

```
NSString *geluid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RG_%@", nummer];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:geluid ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [theAudio play];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    avplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [avplayer prepareToPlay];
    [avplayer play];
```

For example: You hear "Ssstop here", in stead off "Stop here".
Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code running two AVAudioPlayer instances at the same time ?
Why are you using both avplayer and theAudio ?
From looking at it it looks like you should get rid of one of them...